Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference in Firebase Messaging token callback
I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to request push notification tokens in my Android app. I have a function requestPushToken that takes an OnTokenResult callback interface as a parameter. This callback is supposed to be invoked with the token string when the token is successfully retrieved or with null if there's a failure.
Here's the implementation of requestPushToken:
interface OnTokenResult {
    void onToken(@Nullable String token);
}

public void requestPushToken(@NonNull OnTokenResult onTokenResult) {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
        .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            onTokenResult.onToken(null);
        })
        .addOnSuccessListener(token -> {
            onTokenResult.onToken(token);
        });
}

And here's how I'm calling this function:
push.requestPushToken(token -> {
    //...
    sendPushTokenToServer(new PushModel(token, push.getPushType()));
});

However, I'm getting frequent crashes with the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'IPush$OnTokenResult.onToken(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This error suggests that the onTokenResult callback is null when it's being invoked, but I can't understand how or why this could happen. The callback is being passed as a non-null argument to the requestPushToken method.
I've tried checking for null before invoking the callback, like this:
.addOnSuccessListener(token -> {
    if (onTokenResult != null) {
        onTokenResult.onToken(token);
    }
})

This approach seems to prevent the crashes, but I'd like to understand the root cause of why onTokenResult might be null when it's being invoked. Simply checking for null before invoking the callback is a workaround, but it doesn't address the underlying issue.
Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this NullPointerException and what could be causing the onTokenResult callback to become null?
